# How to create a lazy-seq that repeats elements of another collection, in random order?

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I would like to create a lazy sequence that repeats elements from another collection. It should generate one of each element before repeating. And the order of elements must be random.

Here's what it should behave like:

```lisp
=> (take 10 x)
(B A C B A C A B C C)
```

This seems to work:

```lisp
(def x (lazy-seq (concat (lazy-seq (shuffle ['A 'B 'C])) x)))
```

However it is using two `lazy-seq`'s. Is there a way to write this sort of lazy sequence by using just one `lazy-seq`?

If this cannot be done with one `lazy-seq`, how do values get generated? Since my collection has only three items, I expect the inner lazy-seq to be calculated completely in the first chunk.

Before coming up with the sequence above I tried the one below:

```lisp
=> (def x (lazy-seq (concat (shuffle ['A 'B 'C]) x)))

=> (take 10 x)
(C A B C A B C A B C)
```

I would appreciate any explanation why this one doesn't randomize each batch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just repeating the sequence and then mapcatting over it with the shuffle function? Here is an example:

```
(take 10 (mapcat shuffle (repeat ['A 'B 'C])))
;=> (B C A B A C B A C B)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would appreciate any explanation why this one doesn't randomize each batch.

Your `(shuffle '[a b c])` is evaluated only once, when beginning of the sequence is realized, then the shuffled list is used again and again.

Here is a little test:

```
user> (defn test-fnc [coll]
        (do (print "boom!")
            (shuffle coll)))
;; => #'user/test-fnc
user> (def x (lazy-seq (concat (test-fnc '[a b c]) x)))
;; => #'user/x
user> (take 10 x)
;; => (boom!b c a b c a b c a b)
user> (take 10 x)
;; => (b c a b c a b c a b)
```

You also can use [`lazy-cat`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-cat) instead:

```
user> (def x (lazy-cat (shuffle '[a b c]) x))
;; => #'user/x
```

but is won't solve your problem :-)

This happens because of [`lazy-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq):

> Takes a body of expressions that returns an `ISeq` or `nil`, and yields a Seqable object that will invoke the body only the first time seq is called, and will cache the result and return it on all subsequent seq calls.

---

If you rewrite your definition in terms of function calls:

```
(defn x [] (lazy-seq (concat (shuffle ['A 'B 'C]) (x))))
```

it will work:

```
user> (take 10 (x))
;; => (C B A C A B B A C B)
```

because there will be different lazy seq on every call, not the same cached seq that repeats itself.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I don't know why it's downvoted. Your solution uses a function, which is not ideal for me, but it does shed some light to the underlying issue of caching.

I'm not surprised this turned out a RTFM issue for me. But I've posted this hoping that it will benefit others as well.

Comment: @muhuk, Hmm, I don't see that it is downvoted, for me it has score: 1 up and 0 down..

Comment: Aren't they `1` when created? (I'm probably confusing with some other service. Nvm me.)